# Amplify Android - The client issued a subsequent call to `Amplify.configure` after the first had already succeeded

Tags: android, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I created a function to upload an image to AWS S3 bucket. The function is
called when a button is pressed. This works for first instance after a new
Gradle build. But when I try to call the function again, I get the following
error:

```
E/StorageQuickstart: The client issued a subsequent call to `Amplify.configure`
after the first had already succeeded.
```

```java
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Upload to AWS S3
        File imageFile = new File(imgFilePath);
        uploadImage(imageFile.getName(), imgFilePath);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Function:

```java
// AWS Amplify
private void uploadImage(String imageName, String imageAbsolutePath) {
    // Amplify Initialize
    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(getApplicationContext(), new Callback<UserStateDetails>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(UserStateDetails userStateDetails) {
            try {
                Amplify.addPlugin(new AWSS3StoragePlugin());
                Amplify.configure(getApplicationContext());
                Log.i("StorageQuickstart", "Amplify Initialized");
                Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
                    imageName,
                    imageAbsolutePath,
                    new ResultListener<StorageUploadFileResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(StorageUploadFileResult result) {
                            Log.i("StorageQuickStart", "Successfully uploaded: " + result.getKey());
                            Log.i("ImageURL", getS3ObjectUrl(imageName));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable error) {
                            Log.e("StorageQuickstart", "Upload error.", error);
                        }
                    }
                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("StorageQuickstart", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.e("StorageQuickstart", "Initialization error.", e);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize()` method gets called, every time you click the button. Whereas initialization should be done only once. So, You can call `AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize()` method either in the Launcher Activity or you can use it in Application class as mentioned in the initialize Amplify section in the [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started?platform=android#install-amplify-libraries)